# Java: Clear selection from JTable by clicking on other space of the form

Tags: java, swing, jtable, focus, focuslistener

What's the best way to clear selection from JTable by clicking on other space of the form?
I tried this:

```
    table1.addFocusListener(new MyTableFocusListener());

    ...

    public class MyTableFocusListener implements FocusListener {
        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)
        {
            table1.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        }

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)
        {
        }
    }
```

but got exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

Comment: Have you just tried using [`JTable#clearSelection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#clearSelection())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the best way to clear selection from JTable by clicking on
>   other space of the form?

It sounds like a job for [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) instead of [FocusListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusListener.html). Lets say your table is placed in some panel in your form. For instance:

```
final JTable table = new JTable(model);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

JPanel formContent = new JPanel();
formContent.add(scrollPane);
```

You can add a `MouseListener` to this panel and use `JTable.clearSelection()` method as @MadProgramer has suggested:

```
formContent.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if(!table.contains(e.getPoint())) { // contains(Point point) method is inherited from java.awt.Component
            table.clearSelection();
        }
    }            
});
```

Take a look to:

- [JTable.clearSelection()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#clearSelection%28%29)
- [Component.contains(Point point)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#contains%28java.awt.Point%29)
- [MouseAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html)